# Basics of Using Python Nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am fairly new to programming and I am trying to learn the python Nose module for testing a code (myscript.py) that takes 2 input files and writes 2 output files. I want to write a test.py script (to run using Nose) that will take a bunch of test files, run them as input files, and then evaluate the output files by comparing them to known output. I understand that it is better to test functions individually, but my questions are applicable to either scenario.

Here is my confusion. How do I specify that test.py is supposed to run on myscript.py? Does test.py need to actually open up myscript.py? If so, I presume I would "import myscript.py"? Could/should I actually generate input/output files during testing, or should I use something like StringIO?

Comment: I'd note that the line of code would be `import myscript`, not `import myscript.py`. Then you can call functions in myscript.py as follows: `myscript.myfunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a functions which accept text as an argument and return text as well. These functions should be placed in the `myscript.py` and tested in the `tests.py`.